# How can we move secondary IP address of from one NIC to other in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, load-balancing, high-availability, azure-networking

I want to implement HA system on azure, for that I need to move secondary IP address of active vm  to standby vm  as soon failover happens, how can we do this?

Comment: double post https://serverfault.com/questions/1101378/how-to-change-ip-address-of-azure-nic-as-soon-as-azure-load-balancers-health-p

Answer (score 0):

You don't move IP's, you use a service such as an Azure Load Balancer, Azure Front Door, Traffic Manager or similar to distribute traffic to your backends based on whatever rules you require.