# How to change IP address of azure NIC, as soon as azure load-balancer's health probe detect instance unhealthy?

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, azure-networking

I have two machines in backendpool of azure LB,
I would like to update network interface usign rest api as soon as health probe detects vm is unhealthy.
is there any way to to recoginse that event happened and then modify network interface?
is there any way we can achive this with, alert detection and executing powershell script?

Comment: double post https://serverfault.com/questions/1101376/how-can-we-move-secondary-ip-address-of-from-one-nic-to-other-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

That's not how load balancing works. When you setup an Azure load balancer it will send traffic to any of your backends configured in the load balancer, unless they are unhealthy. So, if you configure this correctly then you do not need to do anything in event of of an unhealthy backend, it will be done for you.

You just need to make sure that the health probes you configured on the load balancer give an accurate view of the health of the service.